# Play framework async action: Future recover not working

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework, future

I have following code in my play 2 app:

**Controller:**

```
...
    def getUserById(id: Long) = Action.async {
        try {
          userService.findById(id)
            .map(u => Ok(Json.toJson(u))
            .recover {
              case e: Exception => Ok("Exception got")
            }
        }
      }
...
```

**Service:**

```
...
  override def findAll: Future[Seq[User]] = {
    throw new Exception("Error 1")
  }
...
```

But in controller I cannot catch exception thrown in the service (recover block somehow ignored). Instead, play standard error page with Exception "Error 1" is displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should `Future.failed(new Exception("Error 1"))`

Answer (score 6):

Your code throws an exception before returning a `Future`, so you should either:

```
override def findAll: Future[Seq[User]] = Future {
  throw new Exception("Error 1")
}
```

or just:

```
override def findAll: Future[Seq[User]] = 
  Future.failed(new Exception("Error 1"))
```

In that way - an exception will be wrapped inside `Future`'s instance, so every subscriber can get it asynchronously and process by `recover`. Otherwise you'd had to process a failure synchronously by wrapping it with `try{ findAll(...) } catch {...}`.

P.S. throwing an exception [is not referentially transparent](http://www.bagdemir.com/2015/02/15/referential-transparency-for-exceptions/), so that's why sometimes it's hard to understand the behaviour. The approach with error being wrapped into a `Future` is more pure, so I'd prefer that to make code more clear.

Comment: wow,  thanks, it was not obvious at first glance, now clear for me.

Comment: by the way, how should try catch look like in async action? After your answer, I have ...  try{} catch { case e: Exception => {val f = Future {} f.map(_ => Ok("Exception !!!")) }... Is there another way to return future in catch block?

Comment: @moreo My answer is actually not recommending you to use `try {} catch` at all. All you need is the same recover that you had before, just don't throw exception from your method - use `def findAll = Future.failed(new Exception("Error 1"))` instead and then something like : `findAll.map(...).recover(e => Ok(ErrorCode, e.getMessage))`

Comment: @moreo if you're ought to catch some unknown exception (like some external service is throwing it - I believe it's better to do inside `def findAll`, like `flatMap` then: `def findAll = try{serviceThatMightThrowUncheckedException(); some other code...} catch {case NonFatal(e) => Future.failed(e)}` (you can also use `scala.util.Try`)

Comment: Damn, just saw this answer. My app is full of `throw new Exception(msg)` inside futures, instead of `Future.failure(new Exception(msg))`